# Почему деструктор глобальных экземпляров класса вызывается в обратном порядке?

Tags: c++, конструктор, деструктор

Почему деструкторы глобальных объектов вызываются в обратном порядке?  Я понимаю, про локальные экземпляры класса, они создаются на стеке, а стек работает по принципу: "последний вошёл, первый вышел", но почему так происходит у глобальных объектов я не понимаю.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вас интересует ответ "почему именно так написано в стандарте", а не просто тот факт, что "так написано в стандарте"?

Comment: А как вы себе это представляете в противном случае. Каскадное удаление? Так вот оно тоже удаляет сначала вложенные объекты. Вот и получается ваш стек

Comment: Представим на минутку, что создание А требует сначала создания Б и так далее - так что если удалять не в том порядке, могут быть проблемы. Так что лучше прописать раз и навсегда общее правило - удаление в обратном созданию порядке. Так сразу решается масса очевидных и неочевидных проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим два объекта `a` и `b`. У них будет время жизни. Прерывистые чёрточки - время. Скобки - конструктор и деструктор объекта. Имя объекта записано между скобками. Времена жизни объектов могут сочетаться следующим образом:

```
   [a]             [ a ]           [  a  ]
1. -------      2. -------      3. -------
       [b]           [ b ]           [b]


     [a]             [ a ]
4. -------      5. -------
   [  b  ]         [ b ]


       [a]
6. -------
   [b]
```

Все шесть вариантов возможны если `a` и `b` не зависят друг от друга. Пусть теперь `a` использует `b`. Самое безопасное сочетание времён жизни тогда 4: `b` рождается до `a` и умирает позже. Нет опасности обратиться к неинициалированной или уже освобождённой памяти.

Наоборот: `b` использует `a`. Самый безопасный вариант тогда третий.

В обоих сценариях порядок уничтожения противоположен порядку создания. Вот и всё обоснование: стековый порядок конструирования уменьшает число потенциальных ошибок.